# Best way to turn JSON change into event

Tags: javascript, json

I'm  creating a YouTube upload notification bot for a Discord Server I am in using the YouTube RSS Feed and am having problems with it. I have issues with the bot sending the same video twice even though I've tried everything to fix it. The bot cycles through different users in a `for` loop and checks the user's latest video's ID with one stored in a JSON file. If they do not match, it sends a message and updates the JSON. Here is my current code:

```js
function update(videoId, n) {
    var u = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./jsons/uploads.json"))
    u[n].id = videoId
    fs.writeFile("./jsons/uploads.json", JSON.stringify(u, null, 2), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // client.channels.cache.get("776895633033396284").send()
        console.log('Hey, Listen! ' + n + ' just released a new video! Go watch it: https://youtu.be/' + videoId + "\n\n")

    });
}


async function uploadHandler() {
    try {
        var u = require('./jsons/uploads.json');
        var users = require('./jsons/users.json');
        for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(users).length; i++) {
            //       sleep(1000)
            setTimeout(function(i) {
                var username = Object.keys(users)[i]
                let xml = f("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=" + users[username]).text()
                parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {} else {
                        let videoId = result.feed.entry[0]["yt:videoId"][0]
                        let isMatch = u[username].id == videoId ? true : false
                        if (isMatch) {} else {
                            if (!isMatch) {
                                u[username] = videoId
                                update(videoId, username)



                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            }, i * 1000, i)
        }


    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

My code is rather simple but I've had the same issue with other codes that use this method; therefore what would be the best way to accomplish this? Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code that I would call out right off the bat:

- Empty blocks. You use this especially with your if statements, e.g. `if (condition) {} else { // Do the thing }`. Instead, you should negate the condition, e.g. `if (!condition) { // Do the thing }`.
- You declare the function `uploadHandler` as async, but you never declare that you're doing anything asynchronously. I'm suspecting that `f` is your asynchronous Promise that you're trying to handle.
- You've linked the duration of the timeout to your incrementing variable, so in the first run of your `for` block, the timeout will wait zero seconds (`i` is 0, times 1000), then one second, then two seconds, then three...

Here's a swag at a refactor with some notes that I hope are helpful in there:

```js
// Only require these values once
const u = require('./jsons/uploads.json');
const users = require('./jsons/users.json');

// This just makes the code a little more readable, I think
const URL_BASE = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=';

function uploadHandler() {
  Object.keys(users).forEach(username => {
    // We will run this code once for each username that we find in users
    // I am assuming `f` is a Promise. When it resolves, we'll have xml available to us in the .then method
    f(`${URL_BASE}${username}`).then(xml => {
      parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          const [videoId] = result.feed.entry[0]['yt:videoId']; // We can use destructuring to get element 0 from this nested value

          if (videoId !== u[username].id) {
            // Update the in-memory value for this user's most recent video
            u[username].id = videoId;
            // Console.log the update
            console.log(`Hey listen! ${username} just released a new video! Go watch it: https://youtu.be/${videoId}\n\n`);
            // Attempt to update the json file; this won't affect the u object in memory, but will keep your app up to date
            // when you restart it in the future.
            fs.writeFile('./jsons/uploads.json', JSON.stringify(u, null, 2), err => {
              if (err) {
                console.err(`There was a problem updating uploads.json with the new videoId ${videoId} for user ${username}`);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    })
    // This .catch method will run if the call made by `f` fails for any reason
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
}

// I am assuming that what you want is to check for updates once every second.
setInterval(uploadHandler, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you! To clarify: `f` is sync-fetch, but I'll switch over to regular fetch; the reason I was using async is because I was testing stuff and forgot to remove it. I will try this and see how it works